# Is there a way to throw an exception when string is typed in an arrayc#?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, throw

I am new in this fascinating world of programming. I have done this array, but when I type a non integer it crashes. I have tried many ways like int.Parse(console.readLine)), tryparse(text, out int) and ConvertTo32 ,However it continues saying that "Input string was not in correct format." Thanks

using System;

namespace BubbleSort
{
class Program
{

```
    public static void HelpME(int[] a, int t)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= a.Length - 2; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                {
                    t = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = a[i];
                    a[i] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] num = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] a = new int[5];


        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Input enter {num[0 + x]} of five");
            a[0 + x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                    
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Array is : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
        }


        {

            HelpME(num, 5);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Sorted Array :");

        foreach (int aray in a)
        {
            Console.Write(aray + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why do you want to _throw_ an exception? `Convert.ToInt32` already does that. you could either _catch_ that exception, or use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0), which returns a boolean _telling you if the string could be parsed_. (i recommend reading the manual i linked to learn how to use it)

Comment: I want to protect the program by verifying that only numbers are entered. I am trying to have results that should look like for example " Input number 2 of five" jhljkhlk " an incorrect value was not entered, Try again"                Thanks

Comment: then your solution is to _catch the exception_. or use `TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

you should validate the user unput by using int.TryParse method. If the entered string can be converted to int then only it should be inserted into the array, otherwise the program should ignore that value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] num = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] a = new int[5];


    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Input enter {num[0 + x]} of five");
        int temp = 0;
        
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if(int.TryParse(input, out temp))
        {
          a[0 + x] = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        }
                                
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The Array is : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
    }


    {

        HelpME(num, 5);

    }

    Console.WriteLine("The Sorted Array :");

    foreach (int aray in a)
    {
        Console.Write(aray + " ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I am still trying to have results like this for example " Input number 2 of five", then I type a non integer like dsbkhjdsbk, and I want to obtain this output " an incorrect value was not entered, Try again"

Comment: I solved it by doing this:  if (int.TryParse(input, out temp))
                    {
                        a[0 + x] = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                    }
                    else
                    Console.WriteLine("A correct value was not entered,Try again ", a);

Comment: in the question you didnt ask that you also need a output message for wrong input thats why i didnt inserted the else part in code